# SwiftUI Header title covers row view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a form set up and the header for whatever reason is covering my row view. Has anyone seen something like this? I have another version of a view like this in my app and this problem doesn't occur. The only difference is this Form is a child of a wrapper view.

[image: Example of error]

Form View:

```
var body: some View {
    Form {
        Section(header: Text("Service")) {
            AccountField(value: $serviceName,
                         placeholder: "Service Name/Website")
        }
    }
}
```

Wrapper:

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        EmptyView() // Needed to make compiler happy
        if isEditing {
            UpdateForm(account: account,
                              isEditing: $isEditing) // View with the error
        } else {
            DetailDisplay(account: account,
                                 isEditing: $isEditing)
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

Likely a bug. The error appears on Xcode 13 Beta and iOS 15. But does not happen on Xcode 12 and iOS 14.